# How can I make WireMock port more dynamic to use it for testing service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, github-api, wiremock

I am using wiremock to mock github api to do some testing of my service.
The service calls github api. For the tests I am setting endpoint property to

```
github.api.endpoint=http://localhost:8087
```

This host and port are the same as wiremock server `@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 8087)` so I can test different scenarios like : malformed response, timeouts etc.

How can I make this port dynamic to avoid case when it is already used by system ? Is there a way to get wiremock port in tests and reassign endpoint property ?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 8087)
@TestPropertySource(properties ={"github.api.endpoint=http://localhost:8087"}) 
public class GithubRepositoryServiceTestWithWireMockServer {

@Value("${github.api.client.timeout.milis}")
private int githubClientTimeout;

@Autowired
private GithubRepositoryService service;

@Test
public void getRepositoryDetails() {
    GithubRepositoryDetails expected = new GithubRepositoryDetails("niemar/xf-test", null,
            "https://github.com/niemar/xf-test.git", 1, "2016-06-12T18:46:24Z");
    stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/repos/niemar/xf-test"))
            .willReturn(aResponse().withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").withBodyFile("/okResponse.json")));

    GithubRepositoryDetails repositoryDetails = service.getRepositoryDetails("niemar", "xf-test");

    Assert.assertEquals(expected, repositoryDetails);
}

@Test
public void testTimeout() {
    GithubRepositoryDetails expected = new GithubRepositoryDetails("niemar/xf-test", null,
            "https://github.com/niemar/xf-test.git", 1, "2016-06-12T18:46:24Z");
    stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/repos/niemar/xf-test"))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .withBodyFile("/okResponse.json")
                    .withFixedDelay(githubClientTimeout * 3)));

    boolean wasExceptionThrown = false;
    try {
        GithubRepositoryDetails repositoryDetails = service.getRepositoryDetails("niemar", "xf-test");
    } catch (GithubRepositoryNotFound e) {
        wasExceptionThrown = true;
    }

    Assert.assertTrue(wasExceptionThrown);
}
```

Answer (score 27):

You have to set the WireMock port to 0 so that it chooses a random port and then use a reference to this port (`wiremock.server.port`) as part of the endpoint property.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "github.api.endpoint=http://localhost:${wiremock.server.port}"
}) 
public class GithubRepositoryServiceTestWithWireMockServer {
    ....
}
```

See also [Spring Cloud Contract WireMock](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/project-features.html#features-wiremock).

Comment: Do you know if this property should work for Micronaut as well? I'm getting this error: `Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Could not resolve placeholder ${wiremock.server.port}`

Comment: I finally figured out you need to tell WireMockSpring to actually use this port if you are overriding the Options bean:
`
    @Configuration
    static class Config {
      @Bean Options options(
        @Value("${wiremock.server.port}")
        int wireMockPort) {
    ... 
        return WireMockSpring.options()
          .port(wireMockPort)
`

Answer (score 14):

I know this is a bit old post but still there is a documented way to have these ports dynamically. Read more here: [Getting started](http://wiremock.org/docs/getting-started/). Just scroll down a bit to 'Random port numbers'.
From the documentation there:

What you need to do is to define a Rule like so

```
@Rule
public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(wireMockConfig().dynamicPort().dynamicHttpsPort());
```

And then access them via

```
int port = wireMockRule.port();
int httpsPort = wireMockRule.httpsPort();
```

Answer (score 10):

One more way, you can use dynamic port without conflict is

```
import org.springframework.util.SocketUtils;

int WIREMOCK_PORT = SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort();

public WireMockRule wireMockServer = new WireMockRule(WIREMOCK_PORT);
```

if you want to access it from properties file, then we have `wiremock.server.port`provided by Wiremock

```
"github.api.endpoint=http://localhost:${wiremock.server.port}"
```

Comment: Do you know if this property should work for Micronaut as well? I'm getting this error: `Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Could not resolve placeholder ${wiremock.server.port}`

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of `@AutoConfigureWireMock` but if you are manually starting wiremock and setting up mocks, while starting spring you can setup a random port number utilizing spring random. A sample will look like this

in your wiremock class

```
@Component
public class wiremock {
    @Value("${randomportnumber}")
    private int wiremockPort;

   public void startWiremockServer() {
        WireMock.configureFor("localhost", wiremockPort);
        wireMockServer = new com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().port(wiremockPort).extensions
                (MockedResponseHandler.class));
        wireMockServer.start();
   }

}
```

In your test class

```
//however you want to configure spring
public class wiremock {

    @Value("${github.api.endpoint}")
    private String wiremockHostUrl;

   //use the above url to get stubbed responses.
}
```

in your application.properties file

```
randomportnumber=${random.int[1,9999]}
github.api.endpoint=http://localhost:${randomportnumber}
```

Comment: I will check it

Comment: I will check on weekend

Comment: Not really. Even if I remove wiremock annotation and run stub as WireMockClassRule, the mock server always starts before spring properties are read. Thank for your help.

Comment: @niemar I have updated my answer, aren't you starting wiremock server as I stated above?

Comment: I like the use of `${random.int[1,9999]}` as an alternative to `@AutoConfigureWireMock`,  I used the equivalent `${random.port}` with a Micronaut application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET/C#, you can just start the WireMock server with empty arguments like so:

```cs
var myMockServer = WireMockServer.Start();
```

and then get the port number if you need it like this:

```cs
int portNumber = myMockServer.Port();
```