# Micronaut JWKS keys endpoint mocked with Wiremock dynamic port for testing

Tags: dynamic, port, micronaut, wiremock, jwk

I have a Micronaut application that uses JWT and JWKS.

In my application yaml for tests, I have configured the jwks url as follows:

```yaml
micronaut:
  security:
    token:
      jwt:
        signatures:
          jwks:
            securityservice:
              url: "http://127.0.0.1:9090/keys"
```

I'm using WireMock for mocking the `/keys` endpoint that Micronaut exposes for JWT validation. I have a hard-coded port that matches the configuration one:

```java
new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().port(9090)
```

And everything works fine so far.

The point is that I want to be able to generate a random port to avoid concurrent test collisions with the WireMock port.

So, I've tried with `url: "http://127.0.0.1:${wiremock.server.port}/keys"` ([inspiration from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49374115/how-can-i-make-wiremock-port-more-dynamic-to-use-it-for-testing-service)) as well by using the `micronaut.server.port` set to `-1` and something like `url: "http://127.0.0.1:${micronaut.server.port + 1}/keys"` but non of them are resolved by Micronaut.

Do you know how this could be achieved? Any workaround maybe by not using WireMock and following another approach?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve it by using `${random.port}`.

```yaml
micronaut:
  security:
    token:
      jwt:
        signatures:
          jwks:
            securityservice:
              url: "http://127.0.0.1:${random.port}/keys"
```

After that, I inject my configuration property in the test with:

```java
@Value("${micronaut.security.token.jwt.signatures.jwks.securityservice.url}")
public String configJwksUrl;
```

and finally, I can set the random port in the WireMock port server inside my `@BeforeAll` method:

```java
URL jwksUrl = new URL(configJwksUrl);
jwksApiMockServer = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().port(jwksUrl.getPort())                      
    .notifier(new Slf4jNotifier(log.isDebugEnabled())));
```